# Should I make a SOAP or a REST service to receive files from a .Net WCF Service?

Tags: 7, services

I need to implement a web service client in drupal 7 using the [Web Service Client](https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient) module,  which receives files from a .Net WCF Service.

Should I make a SOAP Service or REST service using WCF such that the web service client can easily implement the file receiving logic in Drupal/PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented SOAP based web service. And for file transfer I have sent the file contents as an array of bytes and it was successfully received in PHP.